# Superposition of simple birth process

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes

Theorem
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent simple birth processes with birth rates $\lambda n$ with the same $\lambda$. Then $X+Y$ is a simple birth process rate $\lambda$

Proof let $Z=X+Y$

\begin{align*}
P(Z_{t+h} &- Z_t = 0 \mid X_t = m, Y_t=n)\\
&= P(X_{t+h} - X_t = 0\mid X_t = m, Y_t=n)P(Y_{t+h} - Y_t = 0\mid X_t = m, Y_t=n)\\ 
&= \big(1-m\lambda h + o(h)\big)\big(1-n\lambda h + o(h)\big)\\
&= 1-(m+n)\lambda h + o(h) 
\end{align*}

Can someone explain to me why the last equality holds, when I multiply out the 2 infinitesimal terms I do not get $1-(m+n)\lambda h + o(h) $

Comment: And what do you get *when [you] multiply out the 2 infinitesimal terms*?

Answer (score 1):

This is more a real analysis question, the probabilistic derivation are nor very formal. So, you have
$$
  (1-m\lambda\cdot h+f(h))(1-n\lambda\cdot h+g(h)) =\dots
$$
where you know that $f,g\in o(h)$ as $h\to0$. As a result,
$$
  ...\; = 1-(m+n)\lambda\cdot h+g(h)  + mn\lambda^2\cdot h^2-n\lambda \cdot hf(h)+g(h)-m\lambda\cdot hg(h)+f(h)g(h)
$$
however
$$
  \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{mn\lambda^2\cdot h^2-n\lambda \cdot hf(h)+g(h)-m\lambda\cdot hg(h)+f(h)g(h)}{h} = 0
$$
and thus
$$
  ...\; = 1-(m+n)\lambda\cdot h+o(h)
$$
where now $o(h)$ includes all the rest.